# insert values coming from different procedure which will run parellely to a table in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I m using **Procedure1**  and **Procedure2** which will  give me values *a,b,c* and *d,e,f* respectively.

**Procedure1**  and **Procedure2** will run parallelarly  and i want to insert these values in 
 in a table **(TABLE1)** using the **Procedure3**.

Plz any one can tell me how i can do this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to make procedure3 accepting input array, in procedure1 and procedure2  you will populate local variable of this array with your values and then simply call procedure3 passing array.

If you want to call them in parallel in oracle then you need to put them into JOB (see DBMS_SCHEDULER_JOB).

Comment: thanks for the comment but plz explain me with a example to support your comment

Comment: Your question is very generic so I can't reply with specific answer neither. where is your difficulty? To pass an array or to create a job?

Comment: i have two procdure proc1 and proc2.In these procdeure DML statement are present which will give me some output. I want to insert these values in to a table . these procedures should Run parallely.So how can i do this

Comment: Sorry, but again it is still very high level. What kind of DML? What output? Do you use returning clause? I don't understand how DML statements (insert/update/delete/merge) could give output else? Please be specific. If you insert or update some rows in 2 procs and let's say want to log modified rows IDs with proc3 then you can use returning clause in proc1 and proc2 to get modified IDs into collection and then pass those collection into proc3 and do whatever you need.

Comment: in both the procedures i m extracting data from table using tabletype. And i want to insert data that into a table

Comment: I still don't get your question... In proc1 you can select from table1 and insert into table3 in single statement, in proc2 you can select from table 2 into insert into table3 and you can run them in parallel. But if you still want to use proc3(don't know why) then select using bulk collect into collection(s), pass collection(s) into proc3 and insert into table3 using forall.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with autonomus transaction 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm

But I'm not sure that the two processes are executed at the same time